# jQuery Autocomplete update source with object - formatting the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

Im trying to dynamically update jQuery UI source. I can do this fine with an array such as:

```
  var arrProducts = ['cheese' , 'bread' ,  'milk'];
```

But need to do it using an object. Before switching to using AJAX, this was working fine on first page load, passing in an array of objects from PHP into Twig:

```
 var arrProducts = [
                      {% for product in allproducts %}
                          {
                              title:  "{{ product.title }}",
                              url:  "{{ product.url }}",                                 
                              label: "{{ product.label }}"                              
                          },
                      {% endfor %}
              ];
```

So , how can I replicate this formatting within javascript?  I've tried this:

```
                           var arrProducts = [];

                            $.each(data.products, function(index, product)
                            {
                                   prod['title'] = product.title;
                                   prod['url'] = product.url;
                                   prod['label'] = product.label;

                                   arrProducts.push(prod);
                            });                          

                           $('.searchBox' ).autocomplete( "option", "source", arrProducts );
```

But that produces nested objects , which then autocomplete seems not to be able to read properly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQueryUI docs indicate that the `source` array should contain objects with both a `label` and `value` properties: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source; you don't have a `value` attribute on your objects.

I'm unclear why this would have worked previously, but here's a modification that worked for me: I changed your `prod['title']` to `prod['value']`, and predeclared `prod` as a local variable so it wouldn't be autoinstantiated as a global.

Also note, I had to change the "options" call to use an anonymous object; for some reason, trying to invoke `$('.searchBox').autocomplete("options", "source", arrProducts);` caused an error in my testing fiddle.

**HTML**

```
​<input type="text" class="searchBox"/>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**JavaScript**

```
var products = [
    {
      title: 'cheese',
      url: 'http://www.example.com',
      label: 'Swiss Cheese'
    },
    {
      title: 'bread',
      url: 'http://www.example.com',
      label: 'Wheat Bread'
    },
    {
      title: 'milk',
      url: 'http://www.example.com',
      label: '1% Milk'},
];

var arrProducts = [];

$.each(products, function(index, product) {
    var prod = {};
    prod['value'] = product.title;
    prod['url'] = product.url;
    prod['label'] = product.label;

    arrProducts.push(prod);
});

$('.searchBox').autocomplete({ source: arrProducts });
```

Comment: Adding in the value was the issue. I then added in a title attribute too.